# In triangle $ABC$ find angle $\angle BAC$ given that...

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

> In triangle $ABC$, $D$ is a point on $BC$ such that $CD=2BD$.Also we know that $\angle B=45$ and $\angle ADC=60$.Find angle $\angle BAC$.

I tried to find two similar triangles but failed! I heared the aimed solution method uses similar triangles...

[image]

Comment: Firstly, you can try to draw a figure.

Comment: I did so, but couldn't get a helpful one...

Comment: Every figure, even moderately false, is helpful !

Comment: So give me some time to draw it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E$ be the orthogonal projection of vertex $C$ onto $AD$ so $CE \perp AD$. Then $CDE$ right-angled with $CDE =\angle \, 60^{\circ}$. Therefore, $$ED = \frac{1}{2} \, CD = BD$$ and $$\angle \, BCE = \angle \, DCE = 30^{\circ}$$ Consequently, triangle $BDE$ is isosceles so $\angle \, DBE = \angle \, DEB = 30^{\circ}$.

[image]

Therefore $\angle \,CBD = \angle \, DBE = 30^{\circ} = \angle \, BCE$ which means that triangle $BCE$ is also isosceles. Hence $$BE = CE$$ Now, after calculating that $$\angle \, ABE = ABC - \angle \, CBE = 45^{\circ} - 30^{\circ} = 15^{\circ} = \angle \, BAE$$ triangle $ABE$ is also isosceles, yielding $$AE = BE$$ Therefore $$AE = CE$$ which means that triangle $ACE$ is isosceles with $\angle \, AEC = 90^{\circ}$. Therefore $\angle \, EAC = 45^{\circ}$. Thus 
$$\angle \, BAC = \angle \, BAE + \angle \, EAC = 15^{\circ} + 45^{\circ} = 60^{\circ}$$

Comment: Bravo:) This is the aimed answer of designers of the question: simple and beautiful,EXCELLENT,it's a pure geometric method

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi This is how I roll! :D

Comment: [+1] Clever answer, although a little long.

Answer (score 1):

From triangle $ABD$, $\frac{1}{\sin 15^\circ} = \frac{AD}{\sin 45^\circ}$ and from triangle $ADC$, we have $\frac{AD}{\sin (120^\circ-\theta)} = \frac{2}{\sin\theta}$ where $\theta = \angle DAC$. Substituting for $AD$ in the second from the first, we get 
$$2\sin 15^\circ \sin(120^\circ-\theta) = \sin 45^\circ \sin \theta$$
This gives $\theta = 45^\circ$. Hence $\angle BAC = 60^\circ$.

Comment: Can you solve it NOT using trigonometric relations??

Comment: If you are willing to grant $AD = \sqrt{3}+1$, then there is a shorter proof. Draw $CE$ such that $\angle DCE=60^\circ$, with $E$ on $AD$. Then $AE= \sqrt{3}-1$ and $AE:EC = \sqrt{3}-1:2 = \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}+1} : 2 = 1:\sqrt{3}+1 = BD:AD$. Hence triangles $ABD$ and $CAE$ are similar.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I am going to give is not shorter than yours but is useful (I think so) in that it presents a general methodology for solving this type of problem, i.e., systematically using $\tan$ function, and basic algebra).

Let $H$ be the foot of the altitude from $A$ on side $BC$.

As the problem is up to a scaling, we can assume that $AH=1.$

Let $CH=x$, $HD=y$ and $DB=z$.

We can build a system of 3 equations with these 3 unknowns:

$y+x=2z,  \ \ \dfrac{1}{x}=\sqrt{3} \ \  and \ \ \ \dfrac{1}{x+z}=1 \ $

(the last ones coming from the computation of certain tangents.)

which gives easily $x,y,z$ (up to you...), from which $\tan(\widehat{ABH})=\dfrac{1}{y}$ giving $\widehat{ABH}$.

Then $\widehat{CAB}=180°-(\widehat{ABH}+\widehat{CBA})=60°$.

Comment: I thought at first I had a solution different from the solution by @Muralidharan, but I was not reasoning on the right figure.

Comment: Thank you,but I'm sure this problem must have another solution not involving trigonometry,cause it has been given to students of grade 9

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $E$ be the projection of $A$ on $BC$ and let us assume $AE=\sqrt{3}$.
We have $ED=1$ and $EB=\sqrt{3}$, from which $DB=\sqrt{3}-1$ and $CE=2\sqrt{3}-3$.
By the Pythagorean theorem, $AB=\sqrt{6}$ and $AC=2\sqrt{6-3\sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{6}(\sqrt{3}-1)$.
By the cosine theorem:

$$\cos\widehat{BAC}=\frac{AB^2+AC^2-BC^2}{2\,AB\cdot AC} = \frac{6+12(2-\sqrt{3})-18(2-\sqrt{3})}{12(\sqrt{3}-1)}=\frac{1}{2}$$
hence $\widehat{BAC}=\color{red}{60^\circ}$ as wanted.

Comment: Thank you,but as I noted before,this problem has been given to students of grade 9 in Iran.Do you know any simpler solution(probably using similar triangles)?

Comment: @HamidRezaEbrahimi: it is not difficult to prove that $AD$ and $AE$ are symmetric with respect to the angle bisector of $\widehat{BAC}$ and such angle bisector meets $BC$ at the symmetric of $C$ wrt $E$. The same conclusion easily follows, but it is quite non-trivial to notice the previous facts.